# Does pulling from a remote give the branches a different history?

Tags: git

If two people are working on branches that are tracking the same remote branch and one pushes first, then the second cannot push until they've updated their branch with the other person's changes.

So if I'm the second person, what happens to my history after I've done a pull? Do I get a single merge commit or does it do a rebase and put my changes at the end of the what the other person has done?

If its the former, then doesn't this mean that even though my branch is tracking the remote branch, it actually has a different history?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how you pull the changes in

Doing `git pull` results in a merge commit of your local branch and the remote.

Doing `git pull --rebase` will move your changes to after any changes that have occurred on the remote.

Per the manual http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

`pull` is a combination of the `git fetch` and `git merge` commands.  Adding the `--rebase` changes the second command to `git rebase`

In both cases your history is different from the remote's as you have your commit (and possibly a merge commit) in your local.  Which is why you will see in your status that you are 'ahead X commits'.  Until you push, in which case then the remote and your local histories will be the same... until someone else pushes.

In the `git pull` case, if you were to look at the history with `git log --graph`.  You will see the history split before your commit (this is the last commit that you had from the remote at the time).  Then there will be a branch showing the second person's commit and another with your commit.  These branches will join at a third commit saying something like "merging branch master into master".  This is the merge commit resolving the differences between your branch and the remote.

Doing `git pull --rebase`, the log will be one line with the second person's commit followed by your commit.

Comment: How can they be the same again? If remote has commit A that I don't have and I have commit B commited locally then after the pull I end up with B followed by merge of A. After my push of my B stuff, aren't the commits now in the opposite order? :)

Comment: Because when you do a `git pull` you get commit A, commit B and a merge commit.  So you will have an extra commit resolving the differences between your branches.  When you push the merge commit and commit B will be added to the remote's history.  Git doesn't look at time as to when the commits happened rather as to what was the previous commit and what is the next one.

Comment: OK, I best do some experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

When you both work off the same commit, you're forking the branch. Branches can pull other branches together with a merge commit, but they can't split apart and still be one branch. To follow two separate lines of development, you need a name for each branch head. When you and another person are creating a single line of commits on your own repos, you're free to keep using the same branch head name, because you don't even know there's other work elsewhere.

When you want to pull them back together with `git pull`, however, you need to resolve that. You can either `git pull --rebase`, which finds the point at which you diverged and replays your commits from that point forward on top of the fetched commits from the other person (changing your history), or - by default - merge the incoming commits from the server into your branch to bring the latest commits of both branches together.

This effectively adds a new commit on top of both of your branches (thus not changing the history on the server, but merely adding one to it), and from the standpoint of the server's copy, the snapshot of the tree is just the server's work plus your merged-in work, so the merge commit's tree just looks like all the work on your branch edited into it in one go. The fact that the merge commit holds a link to both parent hashes means anyone can still see where your changes suddenly came in from, and see the commits on your branch to follow your efforts in a more granular way.

You can think of the server's version of your branch as another branch off your branch. If either of you move ahead, then you've diverged. The way to resolve that locally (i.e. to bring feature back into master) is merging the branches back together, or rebasing one of them on top of the other. The way to resolve two versions of the *same* branch separated across repos is exactly the same - merge one into the other, or rebase one onto the other.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I see now why I was confused. I was under the assumption that Git maintained a single thread of commits as SVN would. Instead it keeps track of the clone branches having diverged.